# Wordpress Astra starter theme - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Recently, while working with the Astra theme for Wordpress, I ran into a problem with importing themes using the dedicated starter theme plugin. Every time I got the "500 Internal Server Error" message. I followed all the steps in the theme manufacturer's troubleshooting [guide](https://wpastra.com/docs/fix-starter-template-importing-issues/),
I also read forums and watched various video guides, but nothing helped with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days, I managed to find a quite unusual solution. I chosed a theme from the startup themes menu, than I pressed the option to import the entire page and in the advanced options I chose only to import widgets and customizer settings (plugin installation options is enabled by default, in my case it installed Elementor and WPForms). With these settings, the installation was successful, then I repeated this process installing only the content.

I think this error is due to the fact that the installation request is taking too long or is transferring too much data. So, a good option is to configure the .htaccess file according to the above-mentioned guide on the manufacturer's website (Just changing .htaccess without "splitting" the installation into two stages did not work for me).

.htaccess file:

```
memory_limit = 512M
max_execution_time = 900
max_input_time = 900
post_max_size = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 720M
```